# "java.lang.NullPointerException" em aplicação JSF com Hibernate

Tags: java, jsf

Minha aplicação web utiliza JSF/Hibernate , mas quando executo um método de pesquisa no BD ele retorna "java.lang.NullPointerException " . Qual será a causa do erro ?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.bean;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import com.entity.DadosPessoais;
import com.filter.DadosPessoaisFilter;
import com.repository.DadosPessoaisRepo;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.inject.Named;


@ViewScoped
@Named
@ManagedBean(name="pesquisa")
public class Pesquisa implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private DadosPessoaisRepo dadospessoaisrepo ;

    private DadosPessoaisFilter filtro;        
    private List<DadosPessoais> militarFiltrado;

    public Pesquisa() {
        filtro = new DadosPessoaisFilter();
    }

    public void pesquisar() {
        militarFiltrado = dadospessoaisrepo.filtrados(filtro);
    }

    public DadosPessoaisFilter getFiltro() {
        return filtro;
    }

    public List<DadosPessoais> getMilitarFiltrado() {
        return militarFiltrado;
    }

}
```

Minha view :

```
<h:form id="cadastro">
                    <p:fieldset style="background: #CDCDB4">
            <center><h2 style="font-family:Trebuchet MS,Arial, Helvetica; font-size:30px; color:#009999;">Pesquisa de Militares</h2></center>
                    </p:fieldset><br/>                 

                    <center><p:panelGrid columns="3" id="painel" style="margin-top: 20px" columnClasses="nome">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome"/>
                            <p:inputText id="nome" size="60" value="#{DadosPessoaisBean.dadospessoais.nome}"/>          
                            <p:commandButton value="Pesquisar" action="#{pesquisa.pesquisar}" update="@form"/>
                        </p:panelGrid></center><br/><br/>

                    <center><p:dataTable value="#{pesquisa.militarFiltrado}" var="tbdados"  id="tabela" style="width:80%;" 
                               emptyMessage="Nenhum produto encontrado." paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" paginatorPosition="bottom"
                               rows="10" paginator="true" >
```

Comment: Cole a pilha de erros aqui. Nos ajude a te ajudar.

Comment: Uma de suas variáveis não esta sendo carregada. mas só com isso não da para sabe o que é.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.bean.Pesquisa.pesquisar(Pesquisa.java:38)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Comment: Alguém que possa me ajudar?

Comment: veja se `dadospessoaisrepo` está sendo injetado corretamente.

Comment: public class DadosPessoaisRepo implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 @Inject
 private EntityManager manager;

 public DadosPessoais guardar(DadosPessoais dadosPessoais) {
  return manager.merge(dadosPessoais);
 }

Comment: A instância de `dadospessoaisrepo` está sendo injetada corretamente na classe `Pesquisa`?

Comment: Essa dúvida também não consegui solucionar sobre injeção na classe Pesquisa ... coloquei  @Inject
                            private DadosPessoaisRepo dadospessoaisrepo ;

Comment: @RenanPompeu, você precisa ter certeza que classe está sendo injetada corretamente. A ausência dela (falha na injecão) lançaria um `NullPointerException`.

Comment: acredito que sim , mas revisei o código e agora está dando erro de  Grave:   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /pesquisa.xhtml @29,95 value="#{pesquisa.filtro.nome}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'pesquisa' resolved to null

Comment: Pesquisei em vários fórum e não encontrei resposta que resolveria minha dúvida